# How to optimize a VBA function in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, optimize

I wrote a function in VBA and have provided a simplified version below.  Basically, it takes an argument, preforms a `vlookup` on a named range in the sheet using the value of the argument, passes the vlookedup value to another function, and finally returns the result.

I use this function a lot.. like 50,000 times in my workbook.  As a result, my workbook is pretty slow to calculate.

Are there some simple changes I could make to this function to optimize it for speed?

Readability is not a concern, I just want to make this thing run faster.  The code must stay in VBA though.

```
Public Function Yield(Name As String, Price As Double)
    Dim DDate As Double
    Dim ConversionFactor As Double
    DDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Name, Range("LookupRange"), 3, 0)
ConversionFactor = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Name, Range("LookupRange"), 7, 0)
Yield = 100 * Application.Run("otherCustomFunction",DDate,ConversionFactor,Price)
End Function
```

Comment: are you sure that indeed vlookup is the responsible for the long time, or can it be the "otherCustomFunction"?

Comment: otherCustomFunction almost certainly has something to do with it, but it's not something I can edit in this scenario.  I would just like to optimize the lookup and variable assignment.

Comment: This question should be on codereview, not on superuser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First strategy: optimize the function itself

### Should double the speed

```
Public Function Yield(Name As String, Price As Double)
    Dim Lookup As Range, rw As Integer
    Set Lookup = Range("LookupRange")
    rw = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Name, Lookup.Resize(ColumnSize:=1), 0)
    
    Yield = 100 * Application.Run("otherCustomFunction", Lookup.Cells(rw, 3), Lookup.Cells(rw, 7), Price)
End Function
```

This because you only lookup the range with name "LookupRange" once instead of twice and you only look for the right line once instead of twice.

## Second strategy: retrieve the range only once upfront

### Probably 4 times as fast

If we retrieve the range in the code that uses the `yield` function, we only have to do that once

```
Public Function Yield(Lookup As Range, Name As String, Price As Double)
    rw = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Name, Lookup.Resize(ColumnSize:=1), 0)
    
    Yield = 100 * Application.Run("otherCustomFunction", Lookup.Cells(rw, 3), Lookup.Cells(rw, 7), Price)
End Function

Public Sub CallingRoutine()
    Dim Lookup As Range, rw As Integer
    Set Lookup = Range("LookupRange")
    
    ' Some code

    For Each someItem In someSet
        Dim amount As Double, Name As String, Price As Double
        
        ' Some code to deter;ine name and price
        
        amount = Yield(Lookup, Name, Price)
        
        ' Some code that used the yield
    Next someThing
End Sub
```

There is a variant of this strategy where you declare Lookup outside all routines, like I do with the dictionary below..

## Third strategy: Put all relevant values in a dictionary

### An order of magnitude faster if you call `Yield` VERY often.

- You look up the named range
- You ask all values from excel at once
- You look up the `Name`s in a dictionary, which is way more efficient than a looking up in a range

This is the code:

```
Public Function Yield(Name As String, Price As Double)
    If LookDict Is Nothing Then
        Set LookDict = New Dictionary
        
        Dim LookVal As Variant, rw As Integer, ToUse As ToUseType
        LookVal = Range("LookupRange").Value
        
        For rw = LBound(LookVal, 1) To UBound(LookVal, 1)
            Set ToUse = New ToUseType
            ToUse.Row3Val = LookVal(rw, 3)
            ToUse.Row7Val = LookVal(rw, 7)
            LookDict.Add LookVal(rw, 1), ToUse
        Next rw
    End If

    Set ToUse = LookDict.Item(Name)
    Yield = 100 * Application.Run("otherCustomFunction", _
                  ToUse.Row3Val, ToUse.Row7Val, Price)
End Function

Public Sub CallingRoutine()
    ' Some code

    For Each someItem In someSet
        Dim amount As Double, Name As String, Price As Double
        
        ' Some code to deter;ine name and price
        
        amount = Yield(Name, Price)
        
        ' Some code that used the yield
    Next someThing
End Sub
```

Comment: If this is insufficient, tell me what are the dimensions of LookupRange, how many time you call this function in one processing cycle and how many different `Name`s you typically look up in one processing cycle.

Comment: Dirk, I appreciate the thorough response.  Unfortunately, 'Price' is a continuous variable so calculating the universe of 'Yield' outputs is unfeasible.  I'm going with your first response and minimizing my lookups.  Hopefully someone else will find the rest of your response helpful!

Answer (score 0):

A few things I'd do -

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Yield(ByVal lookupName As String, ByVal price As Double)
    Dim dDate As Double
    Dim conversionFactor As Double
    Dim foundRow As Long
    foundRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(lookupName, Range("LookupRange"))
    dDate = Range("lookuprange").Cells(foundRow, 3)
    converstionfactor = Range("LookupRange").Cells(foundRow, 7)
    Yield = 100 * otherCustomFunction(dDate, conversionFactor, price)
End Function
```

When you pass arguments you, by default, pass them *ByRef* which is slower than *ByVal* and seeing as how you don't need the *reference* just pass them `ByVal`.

I'm not sure `match` is much quicker than `vlookup` but by using `match` you cut your processes down by half and just reference the row you need.

I also converted the variables to [Standard VBA naming convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s46s4ew(v=vs.140).aspx) names.

You also don't need the `Application.run` for calling your macro. Make sure that is also passing arguments *ByVal*

Comment: Ray, you need to resize `LookupRange` for match to work when defining `foundRow`