# Optimize For Each loop on Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, performance, vba, macros, optimize

I am having a hard time trying to optimize a VBA `For Each` loop that has to parse 10-15k rows in a PivotTable which is based off an Excel Table, all in the same workbook. Currently this takes about 2 minutes to complete, which I would like to improve on since I use this in meetings.

I've searched and found some interesting suggestions such as disabling Screen Updating, Manual Calculations and to "`dim`" my variables as other data types, but I've obtained no difference in speed. I am assuming the `For Each` loop is just not intended for this purpose.

While reading [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1055756/how-to-optimize-a-vba-function-in-excel) Super User post, it looks like I could put the relevant values into a "Dictionary" and would be very fast. The fact that I have two items to filter makes it a little more complicated for me.

I am 'learning by doing' and don't claim to be a VBA coder, so really any help is very much appreciated!

```
Dim pvtTable As PivotTable
Dim pvtField1, pvtField2 As PivotField
Dim pvtItem1, pvtItem2 As PivotItem

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set pvtTable = ws.PivotTables("PTReport")
Set pvtField1 = pvtTable.PivotFields("callNummer")
Set pvtField2 = pvtTable.PivotFields("Destination")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each pvtItem1 In pvtField1.PivotItems
  If InStr(UCase(pvtItem1), "STORE") > 0 Then
    pvtItem1.Visible = True
  Else
    pvtItem1.Visible = False
  End If
Next

For Each pvtItem2 In pvtField2.PivotItems
  If InStr(UCase(pvtItem2), "221") > 0 Then
    pvtItem2.Visible = True
  Else
    pvtItem2.Visible = False
  End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

If I can clarify anything or provide, more details please let me know.

Comment: When processing lots of data in excel, it is recommended to disable calculations at the start of the macro, and enable them at the end. It can speed up a macro 10x or more.

Comment: Thank you for your reponse! I have the code `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the start of the macro (Edited it into the OP - sorry for the confusion)  but that doesn't seem to bring the speed up for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the 20-30K calls to `InStr(UCase())` are the problem. 
I suggest that you define a couple of helper columns. 
For example,
if your “callNummer” and “Destination” data are in Columns `A` and `B`, set

- `Y1` → `=IFERROR(SEARCH("store", A1), 0)`
- `Z1` → `=IFERROR(SEARCH("221", B1), 0)`

and then change your VBA code to check
whether `Yn` and `Zn` are `> 0`. 
This way, the string-in-string checking is done
whenever the “callNummer” and “Destination” data are modified,
and there’s a lot less work for the VBA routine to do. 
And, of course, you can hide the helper columns once you get everything working.

I’m not sure exactly how to translate
your `pvtItemN.Visible = …` statements into this framework.

But even if you cannot get this to work, you can change
the `InStr(UCase(pvtItem2), "221")` test to `InStr(pvtItem2, "221")`. 
If all you’re looking for is a number,
there’s no reason to convert the alphabetic contents of the cell to upper case.

Comment: Thank you Scott, that did the trick! Now the filter runs in seconds, thanks again for opening my eyes there. I have the sheet hidden where the data is in so this worked perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Just before your first for...next loop, add the following code:

```
Dim saveCalc as xlCalculation

With Application
   .ScreenUpdating = False
   saveCalc = .Calculation
   .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With
```

Then, after your second for...next loop, add the following code:

```
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = saveCalc
End With
```

Comment: Thank you Rich! Helped smooth it out and take off a little time